# Cors media confusion

Tags: python, asp.net, html, http, cors

I have an Issue with cors.

I am trying to access an mp3 I have on one server on a web page served by a different machine.

The server is setup with. https://gist.github.com/fxsjy/5465353

When I access the path directly it all works.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-type, Content-Length,Date,Last-Modified,Server" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I have the previous in my web.config and the following on my html.

```
<audio id="myAudio"
       controls="controls"
       src="http://{A IP}:{A PORT}/{A File Path}/{A file}.mp3"
       type="audio/mpeg">
    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

The page response headers Are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcc2Vhbi5oYW5zZm9yZFxEcm9wYm94XE11c2ljbzJcTXVzaWNvMlxNdXNpY28yXEhvbWVcVGVzdA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type, Content-Length,Date,Last-Modified,Server
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 00:20:11 GMT
Content-Length: 1233
```

When I put the Mp3 file locally it works when I access it remotely I get.

```
MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for http://{A IP}:{A PORT}/{A File Path}/{A file}.mp3
```

As an error in chrome console. Firefox loads without errors but does nothing.

Both requests to the mp3 are returned as 200.

The response headers are.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.9
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 00:20:12 GMT
Content-type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 2882414
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 10:31:23 GMT
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong :(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So dont ask me why but adding crossorigin="anonymous" to my audio tag fixes the issue...

```
        <audio id="myAudio"
               controls="controls"
               src="TUNE.mp3"
               type="audio/mpeg"
               crossorigin="anonymous">
```

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=937718

Also I have to add to the server response.

Comment: Some more information about the crossorigin property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes (Very strange that it's needed in addition to the headers)